# CLIP: Cosine Similarity of Text and Image Embeddings is low

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, multimodal

I am using the [HuggingFace CLIP Model](https://huggingface.co/openai/clip-vit-base-patch32) for generating text and image embeddings with `get_text_features` and `get_image_features`. When calculating the cosine similarity it is surprisingly low - especially compared to other embedding models where I am used to values above 0.65. For example, for a photo of [a cat](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Orange_tabby_cat_sitting_on_fallen_leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg/1920px-Orange_tabby_cat_sitting_on_fallen_leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg) and [a dog](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Labrador_Retriever_portrait.jpg/580px-Labrador_Retriever_portrait.jpg) and the texts `["cat", "dog"]` I get the following similarity matrix

```
urls = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Orange_tabby_cat_sitting_on_fallen_leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg/1920px-Orange_tabby_cat_sitting_on_fallen_leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Labrador_Retriever_portrait.jpg/580px-Labrador_Retriever_portrait.jpg",
]
images = [Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw) for url in urls]
texts = ["cat", "dog"]
with torch.no_grad():
    image_inputs = processor(
        text=texts,
        images=images,
        return_tensors="pt",
        padding=True,
        truncation=True,
    )
with torch.no_grad():
    clip_text_embeddings = model.get_text_features(image_inputs["input_ids"])
    clip_text_embeddings = clip_text_embeddings / clip_text_embeddings.norm(
        dim=-1, keepdim=True
    )
    clip_image_embeddings = model.get_image_features(image_inputs["pixel_values"])
    clip_image_embeddings = clip_image_embeddings / clip_image_embeddings.norm(
        dim=-1, keepdim=True
    )
    clip_cos_sim = torch.mm(clip_text_embeddings, clip_image_embeddings.T)
print(clip_cos_sim)

tensor([[0.2696, 0.1795],
        [0.2288, 0.2597]])
```

Are these expected values for CLIP or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example that allows everyone to produce the tensor you posted.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code for the construction.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, I even fine tune it on millions of images for my problem and similarities were low, I think it is related to the model itself, what is important is that the zero shot classification performance is high enough (they optimised clip following that objective and the contrastive loss), so do the final classification comparison based on softmax and top-k, not the similarities